# Update Column With Another Column From Same Table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named items_list:

```
id  item_name   required_number group_id    alcoholic   alt_item    dislciamer  alt_disclaimer
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Draft Beer         1          24          true      Appetizer   Local Brand    null
2   Burger             3          24          false     null          null         null
3   Margarita          10         24          true     Street Corn    null        Only one
4   Alcohol            1          10          true      Burger         null         null
5   Frito Lay           3         10         false      null           null         null
```

And I want to update the `item_name` with the `alt_item` IF the `alcoholic` is TRUE AND it's not NULL.

I tried this query

```
UPDATE items_list rl
SET item_name = rl2.alt_item AND disclaimer = rl2.alt_disclaimer
FROM items_list rl2
WHERE rl.required_number = rl2.required_number AND rl.group_id = 24 AND rl.alt_item IS NOT NULL AND rl.alcoholic = TRUE;
```

But I get: `Query Error: error: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type character varying`

The only boolean I have is the alcoholic option but I don't know why is throwing that error, do I need to change something on my query?

Here's a DB Fiddle for example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7BvUh2FzkDhZhjqFfy1niT/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove AND in the SET clause:

```
UPDATE items_list rl
SET item_name = rl2.alt_item,
disclaimer = rl2.alt_disclaimer
FROM items_list rl2
WHERE rl.required_number = rl2.required_number 
AND rl.group_id = 24 
AND rl.alt_item IS NOT NULL 
AND rl.alcoholic = TRUE;
```

Comment: I cannot believe I missed that, thank you, that solved my problem!